# Methods to create text preview from a font

Tags: python, image, fonts, imagemagick, python-imaging-library

I'm currently using ImageMagick's convert command to create text preview (.png) from .ttf font file. Overall, it's better in auto text positioning despite it failed to read some valid .ttf file sometimes. The speed is not great but acceptable.

PIL's ImageFont looks like is not good at text aligning, often prints bottom-left corner of first character outside canvas.

Does anyone know any better choices beside the above two? I wonder what tech is needed to power the text preview part on sites like myfonts.com with so heavy traffic.

**EDIT**

Example of PIL Font failed to draw fonts correctly. Font used in the example is [Hanford script](http://www.fontspace.com/roger-white/hanford-script)

```
import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
font = ImageFont.truetype('HANFORD_.TTF', 122)
text_width, text_height = font.getsize('Hanford script')
print text_width, text_height
>>> 833 47
img = Image.new('RGBA', (text_width, text_height))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text((0, 0), 'Hanford script', font=font, fill=(0, 0, 0))
img.save('output.png')
```

The output image only contains upper half of "Hanford script".

I tried with imagemagick's convert command:

```
convert -font "HANFORD_.TTF" -background transparent -gravity center -size 830x80 label:'Hanford script' output.png
```

The output image was same as what I got by PIL.

It's not the only font that PIL or imagemagick cannot get correct text size. With some other fonts, like [Ginga](http://www.fontspace.com/billy-argel/ginga), they just amplify text height which result in upper half of output images are blank. Anyone knows the reason?

Comment: Adding some sample code with ImageFont that demonstrates the problem you're having might help someone show you how to avoid it.  I would expect that PIL can provide a completely adequate solution, done right.

Comment: @Peter, I have added some examples. thanks

Comment: Unfortunately the main question is still unanswered. One of the reasons PIL and other software might miscalculate text height is because the font author incorrectly defined ascender and descenders values for it. PIL does this calculation through the use of the FreeType library, so if the font is incorrect the final result is certainly incorrect. Now, there are situations where the font is correct but PIL miscalculates nevertheless. With this HANFORD_.TTF font, PIL is miscalculating, the patch at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821882/pil-cut-off-letters solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine that such sites are driven by a little custom code using something like  [Pango](http://www.pango.org/), or just bare-bones [Freetype](http://www.freetype.org/) at the back end to render to image files.

The images may well never even hit the disc, although I'm sure things are cached where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of off-the-wall, but have you looked at [sIFR (Scalable Inman Flash Replacement)](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr/)? It is used to allow web designers to insert short text chunks (headings and such) with text rendered in any font they choose to use, even though the user does not have it installed locally.

If you were to create a simple web page using sIFR and the served it locally to yourself it might suit your purposes.

Like I said, it's kind of a screwy solution, but ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. A few days ago, I discovered this library. I tried it and it seemed really useful. I share the link as I also had the same problem.

https://github.com/MatteoGuadrini/fontpreview

Example of font preview:

```py
from fontpreview import FontPreview

fp = FontPreview('/tmp/noto.ttf')
fp.save('/tmp/fp.png')
```