# Dynamically Create EPS Files?

Tags: python, eps

Is there a Python Library for creating EPS files dynamically to be downloaded off my website?

Right now I am trying to use `PIL` but the text gets cut off as described in the question [***PIL cuts off top of letters***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821882/pil-cuts-off-top-of-letters).